# Migrating Cassandra to GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cassandra, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am migrating Cassandra to Google Cloud and I have checked out few options like deploying cassandra inside Kubernetes, using Datastax Enterprise on GCP and Portworks etc., but not sure which one to use. Can someone suggest me with better options that you have used to deploy Cassandra on cloud?

Comment: your question is too broad, as it will depend on the use case that you are solving, amount of users, SLA. Also, deploying the database on the cloud doesn't necessarily mean the use of containers or Kubernetes, you can get some GCP GCE instances and install the database in them. In addition, there are some commercial solutions like Datastax Apollo that automates the creation and maintenance of the Cassandra cluster for  you.

Answer (score 1):

As Carlos Monroy mentioned in his comment is correct, this is wide-ranging, it highly depends on the use case, number of users, SLA. I've found these links useful that describes how to deploy Cassandra in [GCE](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/07/click-to-deploy-apache-cassandra-on-google-compute-engine.html) and how to run [Cassandra in GKE](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/cassandra/README.md) with stateful sets. This [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddac/doc/datastax_enterprise/gcp/aboutGCP.html) will guide you to about DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra on GCP Marketplace You can also consider the cost between running those products. You can estimate the charges using [GCP pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).